# Parse JSON file into Java Object which is redirected to JSP page

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

This is my first time using JSON and I would appreciate some help. I have searched for an answer for a couple of days without finding a solution that helps me to get forward. I'm doing a Java Web Application which has these components:

1. Servlet, which recieves a GET call
2. In GET you read a JSON file which contains student data (name, lastname, studentid, courses, course grades)
3. Data must be converted in to Java object
4. Data will be redirected to a JSP page
5. JSP page will display a HTML page, where the data is rendered into a HTML table

I know this is a wonky way to do this, but I only know Java and therefore doing my task this way. Here is my JSON file, Servlet and JSP page. I also have all the POJOs required.

JSONData.json

```
{  "students": [
{
  "student": {
    "name": "Mike",
    "lastname": "Merrit",
    "studentid": 10,
    "course1": {
      "coursename": "Programming",
      "grade": 5
    },
    "course2": {
      "coursename": "Project",
      "grade": 3
    },
    "course3": {
      "coursename": "Java EE",
      "grade": 4
    },
    "startyear": 2015
  }
},
{
  "student": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "lastname": "Lombok",
    "studentid": 20,
    "course1": {
      "coursename": "Business",
      "grade": 4
    },
    "course2": {
      "coursename": "Math",
      "grade": 5
    },
    "course3": {
      "coursename": "Law",
      "grade": 2
    },
    "startyear": 2014
  }
},
{
  "student": {
    "name": "Rick",
    "lastname": "Roberts",
    "studentid": 30,
    "course1": {
      "coursename": "Databases",
      "grade": 3
    },
    "course2": {
      "coursename": "Linux",
      "grade": 3
    },
    "course3": {
      "coursename": "Windows",
      "grade": 5
    },
    "startyear": 2016
  }
}]}
```

GetServlet.java

```
public class GetServlet extends HttpServlet {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void doGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    // JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("JSONData.json"));
        StudentList studentsList = gson.fromJson(reader, StudentList.class);

        request.setAttribute("students", studentsList);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("students.jsp").forward(request,
                response);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

students.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Students</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/students" method="GET">

    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
            <tr>
                <c:out value="${student.name}"/>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm currently confused if JSON file is correctly parsed into Java Object, if not what is it that I'm doing wrong here? I have looked into JSON.Simple, GSON and Jackson without finding an answer that solves my problem.

Also am I correctly sending the data to JSP, because at the moment it's not printing anything? I have done a bit of JSTL coding, but only with SQL databases and POST method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the structure (with explicit servlets and JSPs) required (as for a school assignment)? This style of writing applications has been obsolete for many years.

Comment: Yes it's required, but this is not a school assignment. I have received teaching in this way (my curriculum was made in '09, so that is why I have these old techniques), so that is why I'm doing it this way. I haven't had time to learn new ways, so I would like to keep it as it is.

Comment: JSP is still a viable and very usable way of writing simple java compiled web pages.  In any case, can you post StudentList class, that will determine if Gson::fromJson is doing what is expected.

Comment: Here is a pastebin link to my POJOs: https://pastebin.com/r6dDjA8F

Comment: Any console error?

Comment: No, there aren't any console errors.